# Need to create a RewriteRule in .htaccess for a Magento website

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, magento

I am currently trying to put a RewriteRule into my .htaccess file for my Magento website that will allow me to write a category URL in the following way:

```
http://mydomain.com/dir/<direction>/order/<order>/<Magento category URL path>.html
```

What I am basically looking to do is use my robots.txt file to make some of the category URLs not appear (specifically when you apply a different sort order to the category).

So let's assume I have the following URL:

```
http://mydomain.com/dir/asc/order/sales_index/footwear/mens-work-boots/motorcycle-boots.html
```

I would like that to be rendered just as if it the URL was:

```
http://mydomain.com/footwear/mens-work-boots/motorcycle-boots.html?dir=asc&order=sales_index
```

The code I have put in my .htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^dir/(.*?)/order/(.*?)/(.*?)$ $3.html?dir=$1&order=$2
```

For some reason, when I have this in there, I get a 404 error. Can someone point me in the right direction to make this work for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried with this on my server

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/dir/(.*?)/order/(.*?)/(.*?)$ $4.html?dir=$2&order=$3 [R,L]
```

and when i issue request

```
http://myserver/dir/asc/order/sales_index/footwear/mens-work-boots/motorcycle-boots.html
```

i get proper redirection to

```
http://yuave.dev:81/footwear/mens-work-boots/motorcycle-boots.html.html?dir=asc&order=sales_index
```

May be you are missing [L] flag on your request.